# how to get mail from contact page yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2, contacts

I am using yii2 advance . I want the contact form to send email to admin. but Its not working what should do? I tried in following way=>

```
'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com', //wrote admin email id here
```

also changes
`'useFileTransport' => false,`
 what is exact steps to make it active can any one solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config.php you should also  configure a proper transport  eg for a transport based of gmail account you could use

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        .....
        'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        //
        //
        /* configurazione servizio email da usare in locale (localhost sviluppo) */
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'your_gmail_username@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'your_gmail_password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
```

Comment: hey... thank you ... it is working now... I just gmail account setting==>Allow less secure apps: ON

Comment: In mail I get subject and body... how to get name and email id field? ... where its database?

Comment: doesnt found email id of user who fills contact us form

Comment: this is another question  ...  post a new one with the needed  infos (code, sample, clear term of the question)

Comment: asked new question regarding this but .. someone down vote for it :-( ... problem is admin gets email from himself not from user ..sharing card from gmail==>from: shailesh<pharmadarshu@gmail.com>
to: pharmadarshu@gmail.com
date: 16 October 2017 at 10:54
subject: enquiry
mailed-by: gmail.com
.............In from tag it is email id of admin not of shailesh user... I want email of user how to get it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029938/is-there-db-table-which-have-detais-of-contact-us-form-in-yii2

Comment: given the link of new question to get mail Id of user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029938/how-to-get-email-fields-data-from-contact-us-page-in-the-mail

Comment: have you visit that question and getting my que properly>