# how to get senders email Id in received mail from contact us form in yii2

Tags: yii2, contactus

I am using yii2 default contact us page to get mail from user.. It is working fine but I am getting mail from email which I mention in code, to `adminEmail` which is also my email id.
here is code=>

```
 public function sendEmail($email)
    {
        return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])//want the data from email field..how to achieve that??
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setTextBody($this->body)
            ->send();
    }
```

if I try like this `->setFrom([$this->email => $this->email])` in above code  I get 2 email id in recieved email
    1st `$this->email` is `username` which is mention in mailer of below code
    2nd `$this->email` is email id which is **filled in contact us form** which I want.
in file- common\config\main-local.php

```
 'mailer' => [
                'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                'useFileTransport' => false, 
                'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'pharmadarshu@gmail.com',
                'password' => '*****',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
```

but then I am unable to get **name** ? I want to receive all fields of contact us form i.e. name, email, subject, body ? I fact all are getting properly except **email**? can anyone help??

hope described properly my question..

Comment: Hey,who was the original sender of the email? it looks like you are send mail to yourself.Then don't post your Gmail passwords in here...its risky :)

Comment: ok I'll edit it.. for testing am sending mail to myself.. I have used same email id for both adminEmail and username..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068889/how-to-get-email-field-of-contact-us-form-in-the-email-which-admin-got-yii2  here is the question which i want

Comment: I think you get it from this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068889/how-to-get-email-field-of-contact-us-form-in-the-email-which-admin-got-yii2/47136298?noredirect=1#comment81292635_47136298][1]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default `ContactForm` model you simply need to create a table in database.
It can have fields like `name` and `email`

Add the tableName method in your Contact form model

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%contact_table name}}';
}
```

Then in  Yii contact action after validation call the `save` method

```
/**
 * Displays contact page.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
      //save data
      $model->save();
       //end save
        if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending email.');
        }

        return $this->refresh();
    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Add email to the body

```
 public function sendEmail()
    {

        return Yii::$app
            ->mailer
            ->compose(
                ['html' => 'passwordResetToken-html', 'text' => 'passwordResetToken-text'],
                ['user' => $user]
            )
            ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
            ->setTo($this->email)//$this->email can be added to the message body
            ->setSubject('Password reset for ' . Yii::$app->name)
            ->send();
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get email id of user directly  in the mail received by Admin??

Comment: like this from:   Guestname <guestemail@example.com>

Comment: I have updated the answer,you just need to add the email to message body

Comment: Check this line in the above code ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot']) It will show like this:From  Namexxx<admin@email.com>

Comment: I already have this code for passwordResetToken. where to use in contact us..cant understand

Comment: this is my code................ public function sendEmail($email)
    {
        return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])  /////what should write to get email field here
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setTextBody($this->body)
            ->send();
    }